# There is no installation type menu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am using a Satellite c850 laptop and I am trying to install Ubuntu 21.04 and dual-boot using the UNetbootin tool. I followed many tutorials on YouTube but none of them counter the problem I have (the installation type is missing (install alongside with windows or erase data or something else). I have already unallocated space for the installation.

Also in this person video the menu didn't appear
https://youtu.be/rviHhpK-4iE

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you [edit] your post to include the exact error message you are getting? This will help us better solve your problem.

Comment: Please include the exact steps you are taking and provide clear details about the problem. It's not clear what problem you are experiencing. We don't know what guide you are following or what you are expecting that you aren't seeing.  Include links to the guide you are following.  Consider posting a screenshot.  FYI, There are official tutorials for [creating installation media](https://ubuntu.com/search?q=Create+bootable+usb) and [installing Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).  So why not use those?

Comment: Thanks for responding,  I have  already  tried them but i can not complete the guide because it shows the disk partitions configuration instead of the installation type that contain(install ubuntu alongside with windows, erase data, something else)

Comment: Assuming that Windows is UEFI, did you boot the USB as UEFI?

Comment: My bios mode is legacy and i am not booting from the usb.